# Asynchronous capture from a process output not working properly

Tags: c#

I'm developing a control for a website, where user can upload his PDF, and after the upload a 3rd party CLI-tool launches to verify PDF against certain profile and generate a corresponding report.
The tool mentioned is callas pdfToolbox 4 (available here http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:download[^])

The problem is that on my control at the website I need to display in real-time progress bar of checking the PDF-file. All the AJAX-stuff for this functionality is already written (ajax-postbacks, updates of progress-bar, etc), but there's a problem with asynchronous updates from the process, which launches the pdf-checking tool.

If you launch the tool from command-line window, you can see that, it generates output into standard output stream, which contains progress updates (in percents), as well as possible messages about errors in the PDF-file.

However, if the tool is launched by the process which I create in my web-control, I don't receive the OutputDataReceived events until the check has been finished, and then many OutputDataReceived events come at once, one after one.

My code is the following (I've written a small console-app to test things faster):

```
class Program
{

        static string appString = "path-to-callas-cli";
        static string argString = "path-to-pdf-and-path-to-report-and-path-to-callas-profile";

         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(appString, argString);
            pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            pInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = pInfo;
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
            process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
            process.Start();

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        static void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received async output: " + e.Data);
        }
}
```

As I've said, all the output from Callas CLI comes at once in the end (while the check takes about 35 seconds). To test my own code, I've created a small console app, which outputs numbers 10-20-30-....-100 in 500 milli-second intervals, and it's output is displayed perfectly from the main app, coming with 500ms intervals.

Any ideas?

Comment: It all also depends on **how exactly** you invoke the `pdftoolbox4.exe` utility. Do you wrap it into a `cmd /c` command, like `cmd /c pdftoolbox4.exe ... [params]`??

Comment: no, I don't use the cmd /c
in my case it's straight path to executable with params after

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem, Calling a CLI app from C# .NET from which I needed to get realtime stdOut updates (*progress report of an archiver*), but it didn't send any output until after the process exited (*Not helpful to get a progress report after 10 minutes of compressing*)

From what I understand it is the process's fault, not flushing the stdOut buffer. I couldn't find any way on **.Net** to manually tell the process to flush its stdOut. However, **I found a hacky solution** to be able to read the stdOut in realtime.

All I did was access the `Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte()` method which **does work** and **returns actual bytes sent to the stdOut**. This is pure data including carriage manipulation etc.

Then convert the byte *(seems to be ASCII?)* to a character with `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(..)` and push the character into a `stringBuilder` object. And now, since I have stdOut data, I can deal with it however I want.

**Example**: For my case, I wanted to capture the stdOut word by word and then callback to user to handle each word.

```
// - Standard process
proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.filename = "...";
proc.start();

// - Init some things
int byte_r; // The byte that is going to be read from stdOut
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(); // Append the characters here
Action<String> onStdOutWord; // USERSET from before. Callbacks words read from stdOut

// As long as there is stdOut Data
while( (byte_r = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte()) > -1 )
{   
    // If SPACE or ENTER callback the current word
    if(byte_r==32 || byte_r==13) {
        if(word.Length>0) {
            onStdOutWord(word.ToString());
            word.Clear();
        }
    }else{
        // Append character to string, skip special characters
        if(byte_r>32) {
            word.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(byte_r));
        }
    }//-
}// - end while
```

Then, using the custom callback `onStdOutWord()` I was getting realtime data from the CLI app and handled it to get what I wanted.

**The above is code just a use case** since I wanted to get words, you can alter it and have it work like however you want. *e.g. Not splitting into words and pushing out the entire `stringBuilder` object*?

I know it's 8 years after the original question here, but I spend too much time researching on why I couldn't get stdout data like the OP, and figured to share my solution in case anyone else has the same problem and stumbles upon this page, like I did